# npm run build failed, What is the problem here?

Tags: node.js, npm

What is the problem here?
I tried this:
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm cache clean --force
npm install

```
root@onlinetest:~/mini-kyc-app/client# npm run build

> client@0.1.0 build /root/mini-kyc-app/client
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-09-03T02_25_55_878Z-debug.log
root@onlinetest:~/mini-kyc-app/client#
```

Comment: Please share logs.

Comment: As the error suggest, this might mean that your system is out of memory (which is common if you have an enormous build, for example). That said, share the log file shown at the bottom (/root/.npm/_logs/2020-09-03T02_25_55_878Z-debug.log) to provide more info on the actual root cause.

Comment: Its out memory. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem was apparently in the amount of RAM I had available. Solution: memory swapping

add more swap space follow this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04